# User requirements for granting DocuSign Consent

Tags: docusignapi

I am running a POC for a Service-based DocuSign integration with JWT Authentication.  We would like to leverage embedded sending, enabling multiple customers to send documents for signatures.  I am trying to understand how we will manage users and consent in this scenario.

To grant consent for multiple clients, do we need to have a user created in or organization for each of our customers?  Do these users need to be admins?  Are we able to grant consent to a DocuSign user outside our organization?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So, JWT requires consent of the user, but only once. This process is the same as Auth Code Grant, requires the user has a membership in a DocuSign account, log in (not in an iframe) by either entering their password or using IDP for SSO and then they are asked to allow the integration to access specific resources (eSignature in your case) as well as allow it to impersonate them. That is critical for JWT.
If you want to make it a bit easier, you'll have to become an ISV. As an ISV there are ways to consent to an app for an organization and you can also have some level of control over your customers' accounts.
[Partner Integration Guide for ISVs](https://developers.docusign.com/partner/integration-guide/getting-started-isv)